# create popup table with database data inserted

Tags: java, swing

ok this is a theoretical question. say I have a database connection set up and I run the query

```
"select * from securitysystem.employee"
```

and I wanted to populate a table that would autofit the data returned from the query. How would I do this?

Comment: See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: `i'm really finding it difficult to make this work` - do make what work? Do you know how to read data that is returned in a ResultSet when you do an SQL query. Do you know how to load data into a TableModel?

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Loop through results and convert the results to a Collection of objects (Employee or however else you are modeling them.)
2. Hand the Collection off to your GUI
3. Have the GUI create a new JDialog that contains a JTable.
4. When building the table model for the data it either needs to handle your Collection of objects or you need to convert it to a data format it can handle (example Object[][] for a `DefaultTableModel`).
5. Set the dialog to visible.

Comment: i'm really new to java so i'm really finding it difficult to make this work :(

Comment: You question is too broad for a super detailed answer.   If you are this new to Java, then you should focus on learning some basics because as there are plenty of tutorials that cover all aspects of this common problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get that data back as a double array somehow (ideally you want a table model of some sort, but for quick and dirty a double array is fine).

- Add the **JTable** to a **JScrollPane**.
- Add the JScrollPane to your Panel or Frame.
- Give it maximum stretch (ie. central panel in **BroderLayout** for example)
- Set the **table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(myDoubleArray))**
- Call table.updateUI()

That should do it.

Comment: i'm really new to java so i'm really finding it difficult to make this work :(

Comment: -1 for table.updateUI(). There is never any need to do this. The updateUI() method is used internally by Swing for LAF changes. Swing components will automatically repaint themselves when a property of the component is changed. In this case the `setModel(..)` method is enough to have the table repaint itself.

Comment: I dont think setModel(..) is going to be enough. The app needs to know that the data model has changed.

Comment: need to fireTableModelUpdated() on the table instead of updateUI()

Comment: @OliverWatkins, That is why I down voted. You DO NOT need to invoke the fireTableModelUpdated() method. The table will do what is necessary to make sure the table is repainted. That is the benefit of using Swing. All that is needed it to use the setModel() method.

Comment: If I do setModel(..) Swing can figure it out. but if i change something in my array in my TableModel then Swing has no way of knowing it. Or has Swing dramatically improved in the last releases?

Comment: You should NOT be making changes to the data in the Array. Changes should be made to the TableModel. It is then the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke the appropriate fireXXX() method. The application code itself does not need to do this. This is the whole point of the MVC design of Swing. You change the model and the modeal tells the view to repaint itself.

Comment: This is not an issue of MVC. It all depends where and when you want to call fireXXX(). Sometimes you just want to update a single row or cell with fireTableRowUpdated(..). You are talking about databinding and Swing does not support that yet.